# How do I center the contents of the main page for a React app?

Tags: css, reactjs

This is my first attempt at transferring a design from Figma into code using [Anima](https://www.animaapp.com/) (a design-to-code tool), but for some reason the content will not center.

I used Vite to create the React app and then copied the code generated from Anima.

I tried changing the CSS generated by Anima so that the body uses `display: flex` and `justify-content: center`. I also changed doing the same using `#root { display: flex; justify-content: center }`  since my React app is being rendered (if that's the right word) to the root id in my html file but that did not work.

I'm still learning so please bear with me, and correct me, if I'm using wrong verbiage on aspects of this.

Here is my CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hahmlet:wght@400;700&display=swap');

:root{
  --background-color: #faf6ef;
}

body {
  width: 1440px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}


.desktop .text-wrapper {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  left: 924px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 3034px;
  width: 419px;
}

.content-contact {
  height: 410px;
  left: 188px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2555px;
  width: 1067px;
}

.desktop .overlap-group {
  background-color: #ead4b8;
  height: 410px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1065px;
}

.desktop .div {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 389px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 57px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 285px;
}

.desktop .content-skills {
  height: 395px;
  left: 188px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1988px;
  width: 1069px;
}

.desktop .programming-logos {
  height: 198px;
  left: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 197px;
  width: 1065px;
}

.desktop .skills-heading {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1063px;
}

.desktop .content-projects {
  height: 584px;
  left: 190px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1232px;
  width: 1063px;
}

.desktop .overlap-2 {
  height: 584px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1065px;
}

.desktop .lines {
  height: 481px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 103px;
  width: 1062px;
}

.desktop .project-hyper-links {
  height: 157px;
  left: 672px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 103px;
  width: 393px;
}

.desktop .text-wrapper-2 {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  top: 97px;
  width: 389px;
}

.desktop .text-wrapper-3 {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  top: 0;
  width: 389px;
}

.desktop .text-wrapper-4 {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 387px;
}

.desktop .devicon-github {
  height: 128px;
  left: 62px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 456px;
  width: 128px;
}

.desktop .dots {
  height: 481px;
  left: 515px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 103px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 29px;
}

.desktop .ellipse {
  background-color: #100b05;
  border-radius: 14.5px/13.7px;
  height: 27px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 29px;
}

.desktop .ellipse-2 {
  background-color: #100b05;
  border-radius: 14.5px/13.7px;
  height: 27px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 76px;
  width: 29px;
}

.desktop .ellipse-3 {
  background-color: #100b05;
  border-radius: 14.5px/13.7px;
  height: 27px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 151px;
  width: 29px;
}

.desktop .ellipse-4 {
  background-color: #100b05;
  border-radius: 14.5px/13.7px;
  height: 27px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 227px;
  width: 29px;
}

.desktop .ellipse-5 {
  background-color: #100b05;
  border-radius: 14.5px/13.7px;
  height: 27px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 302px;
  width: 29px;
}

.desktop .ellipse-6 {
  background-color: #100b05;
  border-radius: 14.5px/13.7px;
  height: 27px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 378px;
  width: 29px;
}

.desktop .ellipse-7 {
  background-color: #100b05;
  border-radius: 14.5px/13.7px;
  height: 27px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 454px;
  width: 29px;
}

.desktop .content-about {
  height: 539px;
  left: 186px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 522px;
  width: 1069px;
}

.desktop .p {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  left: 629px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 224px;
  width: 436px;
}

.desktop .hi-i-m-dakota {
  color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 629px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 73px;
  width: 431px;
}

.desktop .span {
  color: #100b05;
}

.desktop .text-wrapper-5 {
  color: #6d9ad5;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.desktop .unsplash {
  background-image: url(./unsplash-giy2ly37kw8.png);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 539px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 586px;
}

.desktop .navbar {
  height: 84px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  width: 1442px;
}

.desktop .overlap-3 {
  height: 84px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1440px;
}

.desktop .overlap-4 {
  height: 75px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  width: 1440px;
}

.desktop .line {
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 74px;
  width: 1440px;
}

.desktop .navbar-2 {
  height: 75px;
  left: 795px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 467px;
}

.desktop .text-wrapper-6 {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 78px;
}

.desktop .text-wrapper-7 {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 117px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 68px;
}

.desktop .text-wrapper-8 {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 223px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.desktop .text-wrapper-9 {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 361px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 98px;
}

.desktop .text-wrapper-10 {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 190px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 359px;
}

.desktop .heading {
  height: 139px;
  left: 348px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 243px;
  width: 746px;
}

.desktop .text-wrapper-11 {
  color: #100b05;
  font-family: 'Hahmlet', serif;
  font-size: 96px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.desktop .additional-lines {
  height: 3080px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1440px;
}

.desktop .overlap-5 {
  height: 3080px;
  position: relative;
}

.desktop .img {
  height: 3080px;
  left: 96px;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
}

.desktop .line-2 {
  height: 3080px;
  left: 1345px;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
}

.desktop .line-3 {
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2975px;
  width: 1440px;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Dakota Grey Bradford</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my React App.jsx:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="desktop">
      <div className="text-wrapper">lorem</div>
      <div className="content-contact">
        <div className="overlap-group">
          <div className="div">Get In Touch</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="content-skills">
        <img className="programming-logos" alt="Programming logos" src="programming-logos.png" />
        <div className="skills-heading">My Skills</div>
      </div>
      <div className="content-projects">
        <div className="overlap-2">
          <img className="lines" alt="Lines" src="lines.png" />
          <div className="project-hyper-links">
            <div className="text-wrapper-2">Project</div>
            <div className="text-wrapper-3">Project</div>
          </div>
          <div className="text-wrapper-4">Projects</div>
          <img className="devicon-github" alt="Devicon github" src="devicon-github.svg" />
          <div className="dots">
            <div className="ellipse" />
            <div className="ellipse-2" />
            <div className="ellipse-3" />
            <div className="ellipse-4" />
            <div className="ellipse-5" />
            <div className="ellipse-6" />
            <div className="ellipse-7" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="content-about">
        <p className="p">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Tortor ut lectus non amet justo non. Dignissim adipiscing massa eget
          ut lectus pharetra nibh sed malesuada. Ut in sed maecenas non amet. Cursus sapien amet lectus ultricies
          aliquet.
        </p>
        <p className="hi-i-m-dakota">
          <span className="span">Hi, I’m </span>
          <span className="text-wrapper-5">Dakota</span>
          <span className="span">.</span>
        </p>
        <div className="unsplash" />
      </div>
      <div className="navbar">
        <div className="overlap-3">
          <div className="overlap-4">
            <img className="line" alt="Line" src="line-1.svg" />
            <div className="navbar-2">
              <div className="text-wrapper-6">About</div>
              <div className="text-wrapper-7">Skills</div>
              <div className="text-wrapper-8">Projects</div>
              <div className="text-wrapper-9">Contact</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="text-wrapper-10">Dakota</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="heading">
        <div className="text-wrapper-11">Web</div>
      </div>
      <div className="additional-lines">
        <div className="overlap-5">
          <img className="img" alt="Line" src="line-4.svg" />
          <img className="line-2" alt="Line" src="line-4.svg" />
          <img className="line-3" alt="Line" src="line-6.svg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here is my main.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Comment: Since you used Anima to generate the codes (I'm guessing it generated all the files - HTML, CSS, etc), the page layout and styling is not properly structured. I've added an answer with some resources to help, but from this experience, you should probably refrain from using the tool unless your designs have layouts that can translate correctly to HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue is mainly with your CSS styling,** there are quite a number of problems with it. I've spotted a few, enough to fix the centering problem but first:

**You used a lot of `position: absolute`.**
This can mess with your layout if you do not fully understand how positioning affects the overall layout and you do not specify `position: relative` for the **appropriate** parent containers. Check these [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

You should try restructuring and restyling the entire page layout, that's the best way to resolve the issue and learn more about CSS. You can also add a screenshot of what the design is supposed to look like, for more help.

**However, to answer your question about centering the page given your current styling,** you should modify your CSS file with the styles below

**i.e.** change `body` and add styling for `.desktop` itself (it is the main page wrapper):

```
body {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}

.desktop {
  position: relative;
  width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This would center your entire page.

However, like I said, **you should learn more about positioning and restructure the entire layout and styling.**

*It is also currently cumbersome to debug*

Comment: Cannot express enough how thankful I am for this! That did indeed fix my issue. I appreciate the feedback as well. I will most definitely look deeper into positioning.

Comment: @Dakota glad I was able to help!